# Magic Square in Python error in Lists but not in Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, magic-square

I have this two versions of a program that generates a magic square of odd order,

**1. using numpy arrays :**

```
import numpy as np

N = 5
magic_square = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=int)

n = 1
i, j = 0, N // 2

while n <= N ** 2:
    magic_square[i, j] = n
    n += 1
    newi, newj = (i - 1) % N, (j + 1) % N
    if magic_square[newi, newj]:
        i += 1
    else:
        i, j = newi, newj

print(magic_square)
```

**2. using lists**

```
N = 5
magic_square = [[0] * N] * N

n = 1
i, j = 0, N // 2

while n <= N ** 2:
    magic_square[i][j] = n
    n += 1
    newi, newj = (i - 1) % N, (j + 1) % N
    if magic_square[newi][newj]:
        i += 1
    else:
        i, j = newi, newj

print(magic_square)
```

But the one which uses lists gives an IndexError: list index out of range for line , magic_square[i][j] = n

Is there any difference in indexing for np arrays and lists ?

If yes, then how do I correct the code containing lists ?

Comment: In the loop, you always increment `i`, so you have an `IndexError`.

Comment: Generating a list with `[[*n]*n` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by hpaulj, don't use `[[0]*N]*N]`

```
>>> l = [[0]*5]*5

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # same as above list
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # same as above list
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # same as above list
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] # same as above list

>>> l[0][0] = 5
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Use

```py
magic_square = [[0 for i in range(N)] for i in range(N)]
```